# Java Package to include methods in other file

Tags: java, methods, package

I want to create a "library" of many methods that I have already written, and then to use these methods in my other programs.

An programming example is in C++: You create a file header.hpp and a test.cpp, innside the test.cpp you include the methods of header.hpp using: #include "header.hpp".

In java there is no such as option, except of package. But I don't know how this works. I don't want to use an actual OOP with interface and implement.

methods.java:

```
public class methods
{
   //methods here.....
}
```

test.java: somehow to include the methods of methods.java.

Thank you.

Edit:

pkg.java

```
package pkg;
public class pkg
{

   public static void functionx(String x)
   {
      System.out.println("Hello ", x);
   }
}
```

test.java

```
import static pkg.A.m;
public class test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      functionx("Name");
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're after `import` statements...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is declaring these methods statically and then use `import` in your other applications. A great example of this is the Apache Commons libraries. http://commons.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to import static methods in Java. For example:

```
package pkg;

public class A {
    public static void m() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then, you can import that method statically:

```
import static pkg.A.m;

class Test {
    void f() {
        m(); // use the static library method
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good to note that statically importing is in *most* cases poor practice. There are reasons why we use namespaces. From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html "So when should you use static import? Very sparingly!"

Comment: I get this error: `methods.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.methods;
^
1 error`

Comment: @Dr.Programmer Your code has lots of issues. For example `System.out.println` does not take two arguments, you named the class `pkg` instead of `A`, so the import can not find the method to import. I'm not sure what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple in java also:

If you have a Class for example: methods.java. you can export it with eclipse for example as *.jar.

than add that jar to any other project Class Path and use your written functions.

```
package com.methods;

public class methods
{
   //methods here.....
}
```

Now, at the other project add to Class Path and you can:

```
import com.methods.*;

//code here
```

Comment: `methods.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.methods;
^
1 error`

Comment: can you post the package class and the class that you imported the class into?